# Can I use Cloud NAT in a Kafka Consumer VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-compute-engine

I have a vm which is used as a Kafka consumer and I need to have an external ip address so that the Kafka server can whitelist us. Our organisation policy does not allow us to assign an external IP address to vms, so I tried to use Cloud NAT (fixed IP).

However, when I connected to the Kafka server, I received an error `org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=xxx, groupId=xxx] Bootstrap broker xx.xx.xx.xx:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected`

I am wondering if Cloud NAT is suitable for my use case? If no, what should I use?

Comment: Well, what `advertised.listeners` did you set on the broker? And does your VPC allow connections to that port?

Comment: for `advertised.listeners`, i have set the external ip of the kafka cluster
and for the VPC, you mean the VPC of the kafka server or consumer?

fyi, I can connect to the Kafka server on my local machine.

Comment: VPC of the cluster for inbound connections... I've not deployed Kafka in GCP before, but have you read over this?  And followed debugging steps there? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/